# TypeError: object.__new__(_hashlib.HASH) is not safe, use _hashlib.HASH.__new__()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hashlib

I am trying to train a ResNet with keras, tensorflow
The model I was using is ResNet50

I have this error message when I add a keras checkpoint to my training process.
Here's my code:

```
def train(batch_size, nb_classes = 5):

    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = loadData(nb_classes) 

    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    x_test = (x_test.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5

    r_model =model(nb_classes,dropout= True)
    model = multi_gpu_model(r_model, gpus=4)
    optim = SGD(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optim,metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.load_weights('/../weights1',True)
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/.../weights2', save_best_only=True)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),shuffle=True,callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

The program crashes when I add this line:
    `checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/.../weights2', save_best_only=True)`

I was searching on the internet, I think it has to be something with `deepcopy` in some functions I used.
But how can I fix it ?

The Error Message:

```
TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d4fe46633cc3> in <module>()
----> 1 train(64)

<ipython-input-10-d02154ab30e5> in train(batch_size, nb_classes)
     18     model.load_weights('/.../weights1',True)
     19     checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/.../weights2', save_best_only=True)
---> 20     history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),shuffle=True,callbacks=[checkpointer])


/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1629                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1630                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1631                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1632 
   1633     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1231                             for l, o in zip(out_labels, val_outs):
   1232                                 epoch_logs['val_' + l] = o
-> 1233             callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
   1234             if callback_model.stop_training:
   1235                 break

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
     71         logs = logs or {}
     72         for callback in self.callbacks:
---> 73             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
     74 
     75     def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    412                             self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
    413                         else:
--> 414                             self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
    415                     else:
    416                         if self.verbose > 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   2554         """
   2555         from ..models import save_model
-> 2556         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   2557 
   2558     def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/models.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    105         f.attrs['model_config'] = json.dumps({
    106             'class_name': model.__class__.__name__,
--> 107             'config': model.get_config()
    108         }, default=get_json_type).encode('utf8')
    109 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in get_config(self)
   2395             model_outputs.append([layer.name, new_node_index, tensor_index])
   2396         config['output_layers'] = model_outputs
-> 2397         return copy.deepcopy(config)
   2398 
   2399     @classmethod

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_list(x, memo)
    217     memo[id(x)] = y
    218     for a in x:
--> 219         y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
    220     return y
    221 d[list] = _deepcopy_list

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_tuple(x, memo)
    224     y = []
    225     for a in x:
--> 226         y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
    227     # We're not going to put the tuple in the memo, but it's still important we
    228     # check for it, in case the tuple contains recursive mutable structures.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_tuple(x, memo)
    224     y = []
    225     for a in x:
--> 226         y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
    227     # We're not going to put the tuple in the memo, but it's still important we
    228     # check for it, in case the tuple contains recursive mutable structures.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    298     if state:
    299         if deep:
--> 300             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    301         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    302             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    298     if state:
    299         if deep:
--> 300             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    301         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    302             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_method(x, memo)
    251 
    252 def _deepcopy_method(x, memo): # Copy instance methods
--> 253     return type(x)(x.__func__, deepcopy(x.__self__, memo))
    254 _deepcopy_dispatch[types.MethodType] = _deepcopy_method
    255 

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    298     if state:
    299         if deep:
--> 300             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    301         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    302             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    298     if state:
    299         if deep:
--> 300             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    301         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    302             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    298     if state:
    299         if deep:
--> 300             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    301         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    302             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    153     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    154     if copier:
--> 155         y = copier(x, memo)
    156     else:
    157         try:

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo)
    244     memo[id(x)] = y
    245     for key, value in x.items():
--> 246         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    247     return y
    248 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    180                             raise Error(
    181                                 "un(deep)copyable object of type %s" % cls)
--> 182                 y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
    183 
    184     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.4/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, info, deep, memo)
    293     if deep:
    294         args = deepcopy(args, memo)
--> 295     y = callable(*args)
    296     memo[id(x)] = y
    297 

/usr/lib/python3.4/copyreg.py in __newobj__(cls, *args)
     86 
     87 def __newobj__(cls, *args):
---> 88     return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
     89 
     90 def __newobj_ex__(cls, args, kwargs):

TypeError: object.__new__(_hashlib.HASH) is not safe, use _hashlib.HASH.__new__()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as I can't spot a problem from your code snippet, but here is roughly what is happening. Keras is trying to save a checkpoint of your model (as you asked it when in you `checkpointer = ...` line). While doing this, it does a `deepcopy` of the model's [configuration](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/017fe07d01751011a054a081d9646d78081c9b3e/keras/engine/topology.py#L2397). Somehow, somewhere deep in this configuration, there is an object (_hashlib.HASH) that cannot be copied. There are many reasons why objects can be uncopyable, for example if they have locks, but it is not important. The important part is to figure out how such an object made it to your model config.

You can change your copy of the keras code (in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py) to try copying each key/value of the `config` dictionary to see which one is the problem. For example, add this just above [this code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/017fe07d01751011a054a081d9646d78081c9b3e/keras/engine/topology.py#L2397)

```
for k, v in config.items():
    print("Copying " + str(k) + " -> " + str(v))
    k_copy = copy.deepcopy(k)
    v_copy = copy.deepcopy(v)
    print("    copied sucessfully")
```

If needed dig deeper and see which attribute of this object is a problem, etc. Finally, try to understand how this object ended up in your model config.